# Sitecore CLI error on executing dotnet sitecore login

Tags: sitecore-cli

On running the below line in powershell script getting error

```
PS C:\Devlopment\eKeystoneHelix\KAO> dotnet sitecore login --authority https://maj-testhelix.identityserver/ --cm http://maj-testhelix/ --allow-write true
```

**Error:**
Logging in to Sitecore. You should see a browser window open shortly.

ClientId `Device` is invalid for device authorization.

Comment: are you able to login to : http://maj-testhelix/sitecore in the browser manually?

Answer (score 0):

you need to login into PowerShell as Admin.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Thanks,
Yamini

Answer (score 0):

By default Sitecore Client ID is `Device` only

Either run PowerShell as admin and Make sure Client ID parameter is there in  USER.Json

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](https://born4joy.wordpress.com/2022/12/28/sitecore-serialization-with-command-line-interface/) provides the solution:

> Sometime after running non-interactive CLI command, you may get error like this “ClientId ‘xxxSitecoreCLIServer’ is invalid for device authorization.”. To fix it, you need to delete user file “user.json” in folder “.sitecore\”, then run following command instead.
>
> `dotnet sitecore login --authority https://si-url --cm https://cm-url --allow-write true --client-credentials false`

Answer (score -1):

Please go to your solution folder and go check if you have .sitecore directory and ensure that you have  user.json file in there, which contains the token, If you don't have it then try to re-create, Assuming you're are using an Admin user or some other account to log into CM node.

Cheers